# Discriminator value from separate table in Hibernate inheritance mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, discriminator

I have two tables, `price_feed` and `price_feed_type`. Price feed will contain the data for different implementations of price feeds.

Now, this would usually be done through the `<discriminator>` tag, with a discriminator field in the `price_feed` table. However, it would be preferable in the context of the system to have this field in the `price_feed_type` table. I've come across the `<discriminator formula="..."/>` method, and tried working with this.

One solution is as follows (assume this is entered in the `formula` attribute):

```
(SELECT implementing_class FROM price_feed_type INNER JOIN price_feed ON price_feed.price_feed_type_id = price_feed_type.price_feed_type_id")
```

Another solution is the following, and I should note that I've tried with both `priceFeedID` and `price_feed.price_feed_type_id`

```
(SELECT implementing_class FROM price_feed_type WHERE price_feed_type.price_feed_type_id = price_feed.price_feed_type)
```

Either one gives the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column timedprice3_.implementing_class does not exist
```

An extra note, without the parantheses, I get the error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT"
```

Any ideas as to how to fix this?

EDIT:

To add what I've found so far:

Using either one, if I do `SELECT *`, and then do `SELECT implementing_class` outside, it gives a different error. Full code:

```
(SELECT implementing_class FROM (SELECT * FROM price_feed_type INNER JOIN price_feed ON price_feed.price_feed_type_id = price_feed_type.price_feed_type_id) AS foo)
```

The error is:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
```